# Why is my player not coming down after jumping?

Tags: java, game-physics

I'm currently trying to code my first GUI game, where the player jumps from obstacle to obstacle. The player is supposed to do a simple jump when the space bar is pressed (without actually moving on the x axis), but when it's pressed, the player will only go up and not come down.

Here are the variables in my code:

```
private int playerY = 415, playerX = 100, score=0, maxHeight = 350;
private float speed=3, jumpStrength, weight=1;
```

Here is my code to make the player jump:

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && playerY>=maxHeight) {
        jumpStrength = 24;
        playerY -= jumpStrength;
        jumpStrength -= weight;
    }
    if (playerY>=maxHeight){
        playerY = maxHeight;
    }
}

public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e )   {}

public void keyReleased( KeyEvent e ){}
```

Does anyone have an idea on why it is not working and how I can fix it?

Comment: Is there a physics engine associated with this code, ie, you have a gravity function in order to bring your player down?!? if not then you will need to implement some code that reads something like "PlayerY += someValue" in order to make them come down.

Comment: You know that you are decreasing the playerY when he is jumping ? `playerY -= jumpStrength;` and you probably should decrease the jumpstrenght before you apply it to the playerY.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the rest of your code looks or how your game works, but this is an Idea I have.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        jumpStrength = 24;
        jumpStrength += weight;
        playerY -= jumpStrength;
    }
    if (playerY>=maxHeight){
        playerY = maxHeight;
    }
}

public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e )   {}

public void keyReleased( KeyEvent e ){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        jumpStrength = 24;
        jumpStrength += weight;
        playerY -= jumpStrength;
    }
    if (playerY<=0){
        playerY = 0;
    }
}
```